# ler arrays em jade

Tags: node.js, jade

Preciso ler um array na minha página jade.

No meu controller estou passando da seguinte forma:

```
res.render('graphics/index', {namesClient:JSON.stringify(namesClient)}
```

No jade estou lendo da seguinte forma:

```
var names= !{JSON.stringify(namesClient)};
```

No entanto, preciso carregar as informações do `namesClient[i].name`, como faço para ler?

Answer (score 1):

Não convertas a array em string entre o Node e o Jade. Passa diretamente

```
res.render('graphics/index', {namesClient:namesClient}
```

e node Jade podes usar `namesClient[i].name`. Só se quiseres passar para o JavaScript (lado do cliente) precisas de converter em string.

Answer (score 1):

```
        - var names= JSON.parse(namesClient);
        - for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
             label [j] #{names[i].name}
```

Comment: Não faz muito sentido converteres em String no Node para "desconverter" no Jade. Podes passar diretamente para o Jade como descrevi na minha resposta.

Comment: Estou usando em outros locais, para que eu conseguisse ler era necessário sair assim.